# Error on Data Pull from Google Analytics Core API V3

Tags: c#, sql-server, google-analytics

We are using Core Reporting V3 API in C# to get the data from Google Analytical data into SQL Server.

We have been using this service for last 5 months, we have got the below  issue 2  times, but after we re-run the package it works fine. Looks like we are pulling the data when your team is loading the data, but not sure. Could you please assist on this issue? Thanks !

```
TblGAGeoQuery_Tbl2   Error Code :-1073450910 Error : The service analytics has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
No such dimension(s): ga:dimension2
No such metric(s): ga:goal3Completions, ga:goal9Completions, ga:goal10Completions, ga:goal2Completions, ga:goal14Completions, ga:goal13Completions [400]
Errors [
    Message[No such dimension(s): ga:dimension2
No such metric(s): ga:goal3Completions, ga:goal9Completions, ga:goal10Completions, ga:goal2Completions, ga:goal14Completions, ga:goal13Completions] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
]
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPrimeOutput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, IDTSBuffer100[] buffers, IntPtr ppBufferWirePacket)   STDWSQL-CDS\CDS
```

Comment: Are you using the custom dimension slot #2?

Comment: Yes correct.  does that take time to build ? thanks !